# Is it possible to scroll within an element with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to scroll down in a specific element on a page.
I have already tried scrolling down like so

```
$('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() + 100
    })
```

Allthough i don't want to scroll the page down, i want to scroll inside an element.
The solution doens't have to be in jquery, but it is prefered

EDIT: Also tried the following

```
$('._1mseJ').eq(0).animate({
        scrollTop: $(window).scrollTop() + 100
    })
```

Comment: Target the different element with the overflow, not `html, body`

Comment: @Taplar, I've tried that, does not work unfortunately

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Comment: Edited. @Taplar

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2481th5s/  Your logic works fine.

Comment: @Taplar I figured that out aswell, allthough it doesn't scroll down there.

Comment: You don't see the scroll in the fiddle?  i do.

Comment: Do you want to scroll to a div with class or id? if yes you should replace it with scrollTop: $("#someID").offset().top or scrollTop: $(".someClass").offset().top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is to scroll to the end:

`$container[0].scrollTop` can be of the range `0` to `$container[0].scrollHeight - $container[0].clientHeight`, which means scrolled to the very end:

```js
let $container = $("#container");

$container.animate({
  scrollTop: $container[0].scrollHeight - $container[0].clientHeight
}, 2000);

$container.on("scroll", function(ev) {
  $container.css({
    background: ($container[0].scrollTop === $container[0].scrollHeight - $container[0].clientHeight) ? "yellow" : "#ffc"
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  font-size: 128px;
  width: 128px;
  height: 160px;
  overflow: scroll;
  border: 1px dotted #07f;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
scrolling by user to the end => yellow background.<br> jQuery scrolling to the end also follows that rule.
<div id="container">
  1 2 3 4 5 6
</div>
```